# SQL Server : I'm getting this message - Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5

Tags: sql, sql-server

The whole message I get:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure ReceiveChat, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 273]
>   Error converting data type varchar to int.

What's wrong with my procedure?

I'm trying to send a reply message to the `[Chats]` table after inserting sender id, receiver id and the chat id (each message has its own chat id).

Then I want to insert the receiver message.

I'm working with a web service:

[image]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReceiveChat
    @Sender INT, 
    @Receiver INT,
    @ChatID INT,
    @SenderMessage NVARCHAR(80)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT [dbo].[Chats].*
    FROM [dbo].[Chats] 
    WHERE ([Sender] = @Sender) AND ([Receiver] = @Receiver) 
      AND ([Chat_ID] = @ChatID)

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Chats] (Chat)
    VALUES (@SenderMessage)
END
```

So after I execute my procedure with:

```
EXEC ReceiveChat 1, 2, 8, 'hello my friend'
```

I want to receive the answer I insert:

```
Chat_ID - Sender    -Receiver   -Chat_Time    -       Chat :
   9    -  1     -      2   -   2018-07-20  15:58 -  hello my friend ?
```

(9 is the new chat_ID).

It seems so simple but it fails. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Can someone show me the right code?

NEW EDIT :
[image: The table i'm taking the keys from]

Comment: Put the **full** error in your post.

Comment: An insert doesn't return a result set, is that what you are wanting? You could do a SELECT after the insert or you could OUTPUT all of the inserted fields to receive back values as output parameters.

Comment: To me it seems like you want to get the Chat_Time as part of the result set, since all other information is identical to what you've inserted (I expect that Chat_ID should be 8 instead of 9...). A SELECT before the INSERT won't help. Either you use the methods described before or you add another variable, selct the current time (e.g. using SELECT @current_datetime = getdate()) and insert all variables into your table including the time. This would avoid to do an additional SELECT or to use the OUTPUT clause (if you're not used to it).

Comment: The error is clear _"Error converting data type varchar to int."_, you need just to do some debugging

Comment: If you insert the value 8 for Chat_ID, how would the return value in the SELECT become 9?

Comment: @Lmu92 - because its a new chat now after I answered

Comment: @Sami How to do the debugging ? I use - Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17

Comment: Read **[How to: Debug Stored Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272701(v=vs.103).aspx)**

Comment: What is the DDL of your table `Chats`? My guess is one of those columns in your query is a `varchar`, not an `int` and you have a value in there that isn't an integer.

Comment: It looks like the error is raising from a DEFAULT or TRIGGER in your table. Would you share the table definition and trigger if any. And BTW looking at your code this SP has no useful purpose. You are querying with given parameters (query is itself odd) and doing an insert with only one parameter. Maybe you should instead clearly define what you are trying to do.

Comment: @CetinBasoz First Hi!, I'm trying to create a procedure that will return an answer to the sender (i have another proc for that too). I'm making an cellular app with a chat for only two users each chat.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. You need to make it clear what you want giving some sample data and output.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I will write a new question - I can't send you a private message this is the problem with this site !WTF

Comment: PMing doesn't help others answer your question. Add the Information to your question. Don't post code as an image either, provide it as text; others won't be able to use the DDL of your table if it's an image. Also, your primary key, why does it include other columns than `ChatID`? `ChatID` is an `IDENTITY` column, there's no need for the other columns to be part of the primary key.